# Using xargs, for each line in file count the occurrences of those lines another

Tags: linux, bash, command, line, xargs

This is a question in a linux (centos 7) academic module that I have found myself stuck on. I have a file of IP's, extracted from a log file. I have sorted the IP's into a new file, removing duplicates.

The question in hand is for each line in the file of unique IP's, search the initial log file for how many times each IP occurs and output a file where each line is simply a count of the IP's occurrences (doesn't contain the actual IP - doesn't make much sense but that's for the next question).

The new file should also only contain the numbers for the 10 highest occurrences.

I am told I should be using xargs, also note this is in no way for any kind of test / exam.

Many Thanks.

Comment: Maybe the idea is to use `xargs` to run multiple greps in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

Using `xargs` for this seems misdirected and inefficient.  With Awk you can traverse the log file just once.

```sh
awk 'NR == FNR { a[$0] = 0; next }
{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i in a) a[$i]++ }
END { for(k in a) if (a[k]) print a[k], k }' iplist.txt logfile.log
```

The Awk idiom `NR == FNR { ...; next }` lets you read the first file into memory, so that you can then check subsequent files against the structure you have in memory.

We read each IP address into the associative array `a` as a key; then in subsequent files we iterate over each word on the line and check if it's one of the keys in `a`; if so, we increment the count in the associative array.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback -- forgot a pair of parentheses.

Comment: And you need some sort+head to get the top 10.

Comment: Yeah, or it could be done in Awk as well inside the `END` block rather easily.

Answer (score 0):

Non-`xargs` oneliner:

```sh
while read -r ip; do grep -Fwc "$ip" logfile; done < ips.txt | sort -rn | head -10
```

One possible `xargs` approach, using it to run several `grep`s in parallel (You can also use GNU `parallel` for this):

```sh
xargs -a ips.txt -I'{}' -n1 -P4 grep -Fwc '{}' logfile | sort -rn | head -10
```

This reads lines from `ips.txt` instead of standard input, and launches up to 4 copies of `grep` at a time, each with a single input line used as the word for that `grep` to count matches of.

Answer (score 0):

With GNU Parallel it would look like this:

```
parallel -j0 --tag grep -wFc {} log < ips | sort -k2nr | head
```

If `log` is big you will want to void reading it again and again, and for that you can use `--tee` as long as you can run one process per IP:

```
cat log | parallel --tee --pipe --tag grep -wFc {} :::: ips | sort -k2nr | head
```

The solution uses GNU Parallel, so you cannot use this solution, if you are not allowed to use perl programs. So this answer is primarily written as reference for others, who do not have that restriction.